# android surfaceview runnable proper way to delay?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler, runnable

Ok, so I can't quite seem to get this to work, I'm trying to find the proper way to add a delay to a surfaceview runnable. I originally started by using just Thread.sleep, but with so many entries on google saying that using a Thread.sleep for a runnable is bad, I've been trying to "properly" use a handler to achieve essentially the same goal. Here is my code so far that I've tested, notice the handler postdelayed notes and placement

```
public class demosf extends Activity {

    OurView v;
    int Measuredwidth;
    int Measuredheight;
    WindowManager w;
    Bitmap whatever;
    LinearLayout llMain;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Measuredwidth = 0;
        Measuredheight = 0;
        whatever = BitmapFactory
                .decodeResource(getResources(), R.raw.dragarrow);

        llMain = new LinearLayout(this);

        setContentView(llMain);
        v = new OurView(demosf.this);

        llMain.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                Measuredwidth = llMain.getWidth();
                Measuredheight = llMain.getHeight();

                llMain.addView(v);
            }
        });
    }
//the Runnable:
    public class OurView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

        Thread t = null;
        SurfaceHolder holder;
        boolean isItOK;
        Handler handler = new Handler();

        public OurView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            holder = getHolder();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //handler.postDelayed placed here freezes app
            while (isItOK) {
                if (!holder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                    continue;
                }
                Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();
                c.drawARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);
                c.drawBitmap(
                        whatever,
                        ((float) this.getWidth() - (float) whatever.getWidth()),
                        ((float) this.getHeight() - (float) whatever
                                .getHeight()), null);
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);

                //handler.postDelayed placed here also freezes app
            }
            //this one isn't reached
            handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }

        public void pause() {
            isItOK = false;
            while (true) {
                try {
                    t.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            }
            t = null;
        }

        public void resume() {
            isItOK = true;
            t = new Thread(this);
            t.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        v.pause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        v.resume();
    }

}
```

so do I just stick with using a Thread.sleep? Or how would I use a Handler here? I'm a newb so any help would be very appreciated =)

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the `Handler` when instantiating `OurView`, which means the handler will use the current thread, in this case the UI thread - which is not what you want.

See [`Looper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html) for how to properly create a `Looper` on a background `Thread`, which can then be used to create a background `Handler`.

There is a helper class called [`HandlerThread`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html) in the framework to do this boilerplate for you.

Comment: so if I want to add a delay, where would I create the HandlerThread? It would seem I have the same problem as before with this, no idea where to create the HandlerThread/Handler. Google results show examples similar to what I saw with the Handler, still gives me no direction. I could really use an example if possible.